# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in angularjs and codeigniter

Tags: java, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have an angularjs app, and codeigniter as the backend and XAMPP as the server. The app is working fine when I run it with my own PC. Now my problem is if I run the app with other computer which has the same network through accessing the ip address in a web browser it has an error like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/j3safetysolutions/index.php/signin?username=hello&password=world. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.18' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

But when I try to access the API (`http://localhost/j3safetysolutions/index.php/signin?username=hello&password=world`) using a web browser in different computer it works fine. I already enabled CORS in my codeigniter PHP script. To properly illustrate my problem here are the source codes:

My PHP script I added to the function construct:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
    $this->load->helper('url');
    //enabling CORS
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    if($method == "OPTIONS") {
        exit();
    }
}
```

My angularjs script when I clicked the button the app will send a request to the server using the IP address:

```
angular.module('j3appApp').controller('signin', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location){ 
$scope.signin = function() { //the button is clicked
    if ($scope.uname != null && $scope.pword != null) {
        $http.get("http://localhost/j3safetysolutions/index.php/signin?username=" +  $scope.uname + "&password=" + $scope.pword).success(function(response) { 
            if (response.returnValue == 'FAILED') {
                alert(response.returnMessage);
            }
            else {
                document.cookie="username=" + response.username + "; path=/";
                window.location = "#/home";
            }
        }).error(function(response){
            alert('An error occured. The server is not responding to the sent request. Please contact the system administrator. Error detail: ' + response);
        });
    }
}
```

}]);

I know that there are too many questions like this but none of the answer of them is working for me. Any idea of yours is very very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, looks like you may have the headers after the output.
"that header() must be called before any actual output is sent"
reference:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php